# Can items saved in Cache be accessed from Console in Browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, caching

I am storing an item in `Cache` on button click

I am able to access this from `label` but not from `browser's cache`

```
protected void FirstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cache.Insert("Test", "Data here");
            UserNameLabel.Text = (string)Cache["Test"];
        }
```

This changes the text of label to `Data here`

But in Google chrome console, when i type `Cache["Test"]` its not returning the value

Comment: Because the `Cache` "collection" is server side, not client side, so you can't access it from Javascript/Chrome Console

Comment: oh !!
i thought it will be cached on client side

Comment: Can we cache on client system?

Comment: Yes, you can use cookies (easily accessible from Javascript code), ViewState (difficult to access from JS code) and Javascript injection in the page, but in all the cases the page gets big

Comment: With Javascript Injection I mean, in the aspx page, something like <script>var mycache = '<%= ResultFromSomeCSharpMethodOrProperty()  %>' // Remember to escape correctly the result of your method :-) </script>

Comment: Or the `ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration` method, if you need to cache an array

Comment: thanks @xanatos i was looking to cache an array :) Please add this as answer so that i can accept answer

Comment: If you like to use the data on a specific web page only, it is better to spill the data into the JS based json object into the html markup. Otherwise, you can stick with the cookie option.